# NoMethodError in BookmarksController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

After installing devise and adding authentication & User model successfully, every time i try an sign up to my web app i can get to the sign in page and login but when i click submit i  get NoMethodError in BookmarksController#index undefined method `page' for #

```
# GET /bookmarks
  def index
error -> @bookmarks = current_user.bookmarks.order('created_at desc').page(params[:page])
  end

  # GET /bookmarks/1
```

bookmarks controller

```
class BookmarksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_bookmark, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /bookmarks
  def index
    @bookmarks = current_user.bookmarks.order('created_at desc').page(params[:page])
  end

  # GET /bookmarks/1
  def show
  end

  # GET /bookmarks/new
  def new
    @bookmark = current_user.bookmarks.new
  end

  # GET /bookmarks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /bookmarks
  def create
    @bookmark = current_user.bookmarks.new(bookmark_params)

    if @bookmark.save
      redirect_to @bookmark, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /bookmarks/1
  def update
    if @bookmark.update(bookmark_params)
      redirect_to @bookmark, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  # DELETE /bookmarks/1
  def destroy
    @bookmark.destroy
    redirect_to bookmarks_url, notice: 'Bookmark was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_bookmark
      unless @bookmark = current_user.bookmarks.where(id: params[:id]).first
        flash[:alert] = 'Bookmark not found.'
        redirect_to root_url
      end
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def bookmark_params
      params.require(:bookmark).permit(:title, :url, :user_id)
    end
end

bookmark.rb
class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

end

user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :bookmarks
end
```

Comment: Are you using will_paginate gem?

Comment: no i am not using will_paginate

Comment: What is page method then which you are calling in `index` action `current_user.bookmarks.order('created_at desc').page(params[:page])`

Comment: it doesn't have a page method so i removed the  .page(params[:page]) and i can now sign in successfully , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove call for `page` method from `index` action:

```
  def index
    @bookmarks = current_user.bookmarks.order('created_at desc')
  end
```

Its not defined anywhere in the given code in the question. `page` method is usually used with `will_paginate` gem and you are not using it, so remove the call.